Laplacian in $S^N$-polar coordinates
It is well-known that using the inverse stereographic projection $$\mathbb{R}^N\ni x\mapsto\left(\frac{2x}{1+|x|^2},\frac{1-|x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\right)\in S^N$$ we can define the metric on $S^N$ as $$g_{S^N}:=\left(\frac2{1+|x|^2}\right)^2dx^2$$ Now I want to verify the following relation in polar coordinates $$\color{blue}{\Delta_{S^N}=\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-N-1}r^{-N}\partial_r\left(\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{N-1}r^N\partial_r\right)+\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-2}r^{-2}\Delta_{S^{N-1}}}$$ We know the Laplace-Beltrami operator is defined as follows $$\Delta_g:=\frac1{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\partial_j\right)$$ So we should get the relation as soon as $g=g_{S^N}$. According to our definition, I calculated $$|g_{S^N}|=\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{2(N+1)}$$ Now if we consider the coordinates on $S^N$ as $(r,\Theta)$ for $0<r\leq1$ and $\Theta\in(0,2\pi]^N$, the metric components are \begin{align*}&g^{rr}_{S^N}=\frac{\text{cofactor}(g_{rr})}{|g_{S^N}|}=\frac{\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{2N}}{\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{2(N+1)}}=\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-2}\\&g^{\Theta\Theta}_{S^N}=\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-2N}\end{align*} So I get the relation (using $\partial_{\Theta\Theta}=\Delta_{S^{N-1}}$) $$\Delta_{S^N}=\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-N-1}\partial_r\left(\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{N-1}\partial_r\right)+\left(\frac2{1+r^2}\right)^{-2N}\Delta_{S^{N-1}}$$ which appears partially wrong since $r^N$ factor is not present and coefficient of $\Delta_{S^{N-1}}$ is also incorrect. I have no idea where it is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.
